# How can I copy Windows 8 app that I've installed on one PC to another?

Tags: windows-8

Some Windows 8 install-able apps have a large size. Rather than download it again on a different PC that I have, is it possible to copy an installed app from the first PC?

Comment: This maybe helpful http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-create-portable-version-of-windows-8/

Comment: This may also be of assistance http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/win8togo

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy installed application. Because it fully merged with registry. So there is no use of it.

Better you search standalone installer for that application or make a ghost of 1st to 2nd.